# Creating DirectShow source filter

Tags: filter, directshow, mplayer

I'm trying to find a way to record an HD IP camera feed in a 3rd party Windows 7 program which uses DirectShow.

The 3rd party program records other specific input signals so I'm stuck with it. In addition, I need to have the video feed sync with the other signals so a delay in the video feed is unacceptable.

I've attempted to do this utilizing different methods with over a dozen cameras. All methods other than the following have resulted in a video lag. (Attempted to use Gstreamer without success)

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to transmit the video feed from an IP camera to a Win 7 PC.

Raspivid is installed on the Pi with the following parameters: -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -hf -ih -fps 20 -o - | nc -k -l 2222

I can view the video feed through Mplayer with no lag by running the command: C:\mplayer\mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es ffmpeg://tcp://192.168.1.6:2222

My problem is that I cannot pipe the feed into the 3rd party program. I believe I need to have a DirectShow source filter created to do this.

Would anyone be able to create a filter to do this or could you direct me to someone who can?

I would be more than happy to compensate someone for the development time.

Thanks much,

Chuck

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the DShow graph? (Use GraphEdit.exe)

Comment: If you're getting video lag check your CPU usage, it's possible you're not using hardware accelerated decoding. Also check for any inadvertent transcoding. Are you certain the lag is in the computer and not the IP camera itself? (IP cameras are not designed for low-latency operation, that's what IIDC/DCAM cameras are for)